Remove share icon from wordpress embed url
image share icon
i remove site icon and home url but i can't remove share icon from WordPress embed feature.
I added this code to my function.php to remove site icon and home url But I want to remove the share icon but I can't
function groovy() {
$site_title = sprintf(
esc_url( home_url() ),
esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )
);
$site_title = '<div class="wp-embed-site-title">' . $site_title . '</div>';

return $site_title;
}
add_filter('embed_site_title_html','__return_false');
add_filter( 'event_manager_event_friend_share', 'wpem_event_manager_event_friend_share' );
function wpem_event_manager_event_friend_share() {
  return false;
}



Do you have content-single-event_listing.php file in theme folder?
